# Images not cached even with max-age set

Tags: html, image, web, http-headers, browser-cache

I'm trying to figure out why images are not cached by the browser like how it works with JS and CSS even though max-age is set.

This is the image I used for testing:

https://www.l-objet.com/_pa/spaces-identity.l-objet/apps/kanvas/themes/l-objet/assets/images/home-jan-2021/1609387872372/home_intro07_desktop.jpg?w=1024

You can see in the screenshot that it's going to the server every time. Can you spot anything that's missing here? I have tested this with Chrome and Safari.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing you are refreshing? That is an explicit signal for the browser to double check the content is fresh, so it Ford go all the way to the server to double check this. If you’d done a normal navigation to the image you would have seen the cached version was used.

For example when I open dev tools (making sure disable cache is not ticked), then click on above link, then come back to this question, then click on link again I see the following:

[image: Screenshot showing Disk Cache being used]

As you can see under the Size column the image was served from the *disk cache*, and you might also notice the 200 status is slightly dimmed compared to the favicon below (which is not cached but probably should be!).

However you would normally expect the server to return a 304 Not Modified response to say “yeah the cached version is fine”, and it didn’t here. To allow the server to do that you need to tell the server which version you have in the cache. This is done by sending a `Last-Modified` or `ETag` header with the original response, and this is then sent in subsequent requests (in a `If-Modified-Since` or `If-None-Matched` header respectively) and a cheaper 304 response is returned without the full payload if it’s not changed, rather than the full 200 download. It’s another sign the content is in the cache (even if it did require a server check to revalidate it first). However your original response does not include either of those headers, so server can’t respond with a 304 and so you get the full 200 download.

Finally I also noticed you’re serving the JPEG with gzip. As JPEG is already a compressed format you shouldn’t gzip on top of that as water effort and often results in bigger, instead of smaller files. Just gzip text files. Not directly related to your question but since I was looking at your headers thought I’d point it out as another thing to fix while you’re at it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I did find similar info regarding refreshing and that isn't the issue. Even if I just follow links, I see the same results.

Comment: Well it works for me when I follow links. Edited answer to add screenshot to show this.

Comment: Turns out max-age alone wasn't good enough. After setting the expires header, they are now consistently cached by the browser.

Comment: That doesn't seem right? Which browser? As I say it worked for me for Chrome.

Comment: I tried in both Chrome and Safari. Both latest version.

Comment: It definitely worked in Chrome without expires header as I tested that as per screenshot above. I’d be interested in hearing in what scenario that didn’t work for you.

Comment: I also found it strange. None of the images were cached locally, but JS and CSS were cached for all cases. Once I added expires header, it started working right away. Based on what I read, this also doesn't make sense to me, but I couldn't explain it either.

Comment: Images definitely worked as per above. And I explained the steps I took. Did you do the same steps?

Comment: Yes, I followed links instead of doing refresh and images were still not cached.